# JAXB unmarshaling xml without qualified namespace prefixes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to marshal object to xml with qualified namespace form (`<prefix:tag-name>`).
And it works fine. 
I have package-info.java file with `@XmlShema(elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)` but xmls I received comes without namespace prefixes (`<tag-name>`).
Is there any way to use namespace prefixes just for marshaling with Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the prefix with the `@XmlNs` annotation inside your `@XmlSchema` annotation:

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "prefix",
                   namespaceURI = "http://mycompany.com/whatever"))
```

Comment: I have such prefix specified. But xmls I try to parse come without prefixes

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you talking about marshalling (writing XML) or unmarshalling (reading / parsing XML)? Why does it matter if there are namespace prefixes or not in the XML?

Comment: XML I'm writing must have namespace prefixes (that's why I have XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) and those I'm reading doesn't have. And I use same POJO for both.

Comment: Ok, but these are strange requirements. For JAXB it doesn't matter if there are prefixes or not, as long as the namespace is configured correctly. It doesn't matter if in the XML you have `xmlns="abc"` and no prefixes `<element>`, or `xmlns:prefix="abc"` and elements with `<prefix:element>`. In the end it means the same.